# Triple booting Chromium Os, Ubuntu 14.10, Windows 7

Tags: partition, dual-boot, chromium-os

I have a lenovo L410, with windows 7 professional pre-installed. On this, I have dual booted Ubuntu 14.10. Now, I want to triple boot with chromium os, but as I have a lot of stuff, I dont want to format or reinstall anything. Can someone help?

Comment: If you have enough space in HDD then you can shrink any of your partition and you can install your third OS into that.

Comment: Use [chromefy](https://github.com/imperador/chromefy) dual boot guide. Just follow the guide at GitHub.

Comment: Thanks, will give it a shot.

Answer (score 2):

If you have enough space in HDD then you can shrink any of your partition and you can install your third Operating System into that.To shrink the partition you can use windows `Disk management` tool or if you have installed ubuntu already then you can use `gparted`It's better if you install the ubuntu after Windows and Chromium because ubuntu's `GRUB` detects all other operating systems.